# Updating a field for all children in self referencing relationship

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

HI all,

I am using Entity Framework and ASP.NET MVC 3. In one part of the app, I have a self -referencing relationship in a table (ID, ParentID, etc...) This table also has a Status field. When a user updates a Status, it needs to update the statuses of all of it's children. The depth is variable.

I'm looking to do this without using the Load() function as I heard that is not efficient. I also came across a way to do it with a stored procedure, but I want this functionality to be done in EF and ideally just in the POST action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is solved in this post:

[Changes Cascading down to children in a Tree structure ASP.NET MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7277316/changes-cascading-down-to-children-in-a-tree-structure-asp-net-mvc-3)

And it was to make a recursive method - i.e. just a method that calls itself again.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Entity Framework is very weak on self-referencing relationships. There are some tricks you can do if there are a finite number of possible levels to your hierarchy, but you'll probably be better off just using a Stored Procedure.

Comment: Do you know any of those tricks? I would like to avoid stored procedures since I'm unfamiliar with them

Comment: @James: The tricks involve coming up with a query to represent the top-level elements you want, then adding onto that query to find the items which are children of those elements, then adding onto that query to find the children of the children, etc., then using a series of `.Concat()` calls to join the queries together. The problem is, you have to know ahead of time what the maximum number of levels is. If you use a stored proc, or maybe even a View, with a `With` clause, it should be simpler, faster, and more robust.